# how to send files to hdfs while keeping their basename

Tags: ftp, hdfs, cloudera, hadoop2, flume

Someone suggest to me, what's the best solution to shipp files from different sources and store them in hdfs based on their names. My situation is : 
I have a server that has large number of files and I need to send them to HDFS. 
Actually I used flume, in its config I tried spooldir and ftp as sources, but both of them has disadvantages.
So any idea, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the hadoop put command:

**put**

Usage: hadoop fs -put [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] [ - |  .. ].

Copy single src, or multiple srcs from local file system to the destination file system. Also reads input from stdin and writes to destination file system if the source is set to “-”

Copying fails if the file already exists, unless the -f flag is given.

**Options**:

-p : Preserves access and modification times, ownership and the permissions. (assuming the permissions can be propagated across filesystems)

-f : Overwrites the destination if it already exists.

-l : Allow DataNode to lazily persist the file to disk, Forces a replication factor of 1. This flag will result in reduced durability. Use with care.

-d : Skip creation of temporary file with the suffix .*COPYING*.

**Examples**:

hadoop fs -put localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile

hadoop fs -put -f localfile1 localfile2 /user/hadoop/hadoopdir

hadoop fs -put -d localfile hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile

hadoop fs -put - hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile Reads the input from stdin.

Exit Code:

Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your attention for my question. 
Actually, I work on FTP server, and  I resolved my problem by adding some additional options to my agent flume to keep %{fileName} during the transfer from FTP server to HDFS sink. Thanks  again :)

Comment: may I know what is your flume.conf file? I am also working for the same as FTP as a source and HDFS as the sink in flume configuration.